# The Service-Linked Role for this Auto Scaling group is not yet ready for use

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling

I'm creating AWS CloudFormation template to add a lambda function as a life cycle hook. But the CloudFormation template deployment failed with below message:

```
The Service-Linked Role for this Auto Scaling group is not yet ready for use.
```

The CF template is written in YAML and the auto scaling group's part is as follows:

```
ServerGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup'
    DependsOn: 
      - VpcStack
      - NodeManagerExecRole
      - NodeManagerSnsTopic
    Properties:
      VPCZoneIdentifier: 
        - !GetAtt [VpcStack, Outputs.Subnet2Id]
      LaunchConfigurationName: !Ref LaunchConfig2
      MinSize: '0'
      MaxSize: !Ref NodesPerZone
      DesiredCapacity: !Ref NodesPerZone
      Cooldown: '300'
      HealthCheckType: EC2
      HealthCheckGracePeriod: '300'
      LoadBalancerNames:
        - !Ref ElasticLoadBalancer    
      LifecycleHookSpecificationList:
        - LifecycleTransition: 'autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCHING'
          LifecycleHookName: NodeManager
          HeartbeatTimeout: 4800
          NotificationTargetARN: !Ref NodeManagerSnsTopic          
          RoleARN: !GetAtt [NodeManagerExecRole, Arn]
```

The code snippet of `NodeManagerExecRole` is like this:

```
NodeManagerExecRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: NodeManager
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "sns:Publish"
                Resource: "arn:aws:sns:*:*:*"
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'logs:CreateLogGroup'
                  - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
                  - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
                Resource: 'arn:aws:logs:*:*:*'
```

I searched in AWS documentation as well as stackoverfolow and didn't find useful information about this error. It's only mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/APIReference/API_CreateAutoScalingGroup.html#API_CreateAutoScalingGroup_Errors) with on detail informaton.

Is there something I'm missing in the template?

Comment: since  you have added the `DependsOn`, looks fine for me, the problem will be something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add a trust policy for autoscaling group to post to SNS.

```
 "Principal": {
    "Service": "autoscaling.amazonaws.com"
  },
```